# Reset Windows system to factory defaults

Tags: windows-xp

A friend just bought a netbook (HP mini 110) with Windows XP but it was the one used for testing in the store (the last one on storage) so it's somewhat filled with stuff from people testing the machine.

How should I go about restoring the system to a ?

As a first step I'm going to create a new User account and delete the old one (from the store).

How do we change the name It's registered to?
What other things should I take in account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's HP's [Recovery procedures](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=3989813&docname=c00608578) for the Mini 110-1037NR.  You probably want to make sure you create recovery discs before initiating any drive reformatting procedures.

Answer (score 2):

HP's have a hidden hard drive that has software that will restore the computer back to factory default. I recommend you follow their procedure for doing this.

Comment: Agreed.  Don't trust that making a new user account and deleting some apps will give you a clean system.  That machine was likely connected to the internet on display.  Anyone browsing the web with it could have contracted any kind of malware on it.

Answer (score -2):

Turn it off then turn it back on tapping F10
Then A BIOS Setup Utility will come
Go to the side a little bit then hit Boot Opitions and do a complete memory test. Then hit F10 again and turn it back off then turn it back on and it will work again. YOU WILL LOSE ALL DATA USING THIS METHOD!

Comment: Not even close.